# Unit Step Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Question: What is $\mathcal{L}\{u(t-1)u(t-2)\}$?

My calculations

$e^{-2}s \mathcal{L}\{u(t+2)-1\}$

$e^{-2}s \mathcal{L}\{t+1\}$

$e^{-2}s (s^{-2}+\frac{1}{2})$

I'm confused, I gotten the wrong answer.. Please point out my mistake

Comment: isn't $u(t-1)u(t-2) = u(t-2)$?

Comment: It is meant to be laplace but i got mistake from it

Comment: I meant $L{u(t-1)u(t-2)} = L{u(t-2)}$.  The inside of your Laplace transform seems to have terms that disappear

Answer (score 1):

First let us recall that, $$\mathcal{L} \{ f(t) u(t - a) \} = e^{-as}\mathcal{L} \{ f(t+a)\}.$$

Let's do this step by step.
Note that for any $f$ defined on $t \geq 0$, the above identity gives us
$$\mathcal{L} \{ f(t) u(t - 2) \} = e^{-2s}\mathcal{L} \{ f(t+2)\}.$$

Therefore if we let $f(t) = u(t -1)$ now, then we get

\begin{align}\mathcal{L} \{ u(t-1) u(t - 2) \} &= e^{-2s}\mathcal{L} \{ u(t-1 + 2)\} \\
&= e^{-2s}\mathcal{L} \{ u(t+1)\}\\
&=e^{-2s} \frac{1}{s} \\
&=  \frac{e^{-2s}}{s}. \end{align}

Alternatively, you may use the fact that $\mathcal{L} \{ u(t-1) u(t - 2) \}= \mathcal{L} \{  u(t - 2) \}$ and apply the identity when $f(t) = 1.$

Answer (score 0):

The **Time Displacement Theorem** ([reference link](http://www.intmath.com/laplace-transformation/4-transform-unit-step-function.php)) says:

> If $F(s)=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$, then $\mathcal{L}\{u(t−a)⋅g(t−a)\}=e^{−as}G(s)$ for some real number $a$.

Applying this theorem, 
\begin{align} \mathcal{L}\{\underbrace{u(t-1)}_{u(t-a)}\underbrace{u(t-2)}_{g(t-a)}\}&=e^{-s}\mathcal{L}\{\underbrace{u(t-2)}_{g(t-a)}\} \\
&= e^{-s} \underbrace{\frac{e^{-2s}}{s}}_{G(s)} \\
&=\frac{e^{-3s}}{s}
\end{align}

Comment: You have $a = 2$ and $a = 3$ in your first line?

Comment: I never said $a=2$ or $a=3$ in the first line. I do not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I was referring to $\mathcal{L}\{\underbrace{u(t-1)}_{u(t-a)}\underbrace{u(t-2)}_{g(t-a)}\}$

Answer (score 0):

Resorting to the definition, in my eyes, is a lot easier. The definition of the unit step is 
$$
\mathcal{U}(t-a)=\begin{cases}
0,& t<a\\
1,& t>a
\end{cases}
$$
and the definition of Laplace transform is
$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s) = \int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt
$$
Now, let's consider your $f(t)$.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s)&=\int_0^{\infty}\mathcal{U}(t-1)\mathcal{U}(t-2)e^{-st}dt\\
&=\int_1^{\infty}\mathcal{U}(t-2)e^{-st}dt\\
&=\int_2^{\infty}e^{-st}dt\\
&=\frac{e^{-2s}}{s}
\end{align}
From the first unit step, we had that argument of the integral was zero up until $t=1$ and then it was $1\cdot\mathcal{U}(t-2)e^{-2s}$, but from the second unit step, we get the argument is zero up until $t=2$ which lead to evaluating 
$$
\int_2^{\infty}e^{-st}dt
$$